# Create and test a queue message by using MQ Visual Edit software

Tags: ibm-mq, mq-visual-edit

I am working on a spring boot project which is related to financial domain.

I am using MQ Visual Edit Software to inject a financial message in a queue and test the message.

Able to successfully connected to Queue manager server and import the message.

But the messages which are import are text files containing the information in the form of xml representation.

```
Message Type
============
MQMT_DATAGRAM
MQMT_REQUEST
MQMT_REPLY
MQMT_REPORT
MQMT_MQE_FIELDS
MQMT_SYSTEM_LAST
MQMT_APPL_FIRST
MQMT_MQE_FIELDS_FROM_MQE
```

Can you explain what is the Message Type we should chose and how to test message in a queue?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Wow.  You are using a really old & outdated release of MQ Visual Edit. Note: Be careful, as it may not support newer releases of MQ.  You should be using the latest release of MQ Visual Edit.

Message Type is defined in the IBM MQ Knowledge Center [here](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/ibm-mq/latest?topic=mqmd-msgtype-mqlong). From the docs:

***MQMT_DATAGRAM***

The message is one that does not require a reply.

***MQMT_REQUEST***

The message is one that requires a reply.

Specify the name of the queue to which to send the reply in the ReplyToQ field. The Report field indicates how to set the MsgId and CorrelId of the reply.

***MQMT_REPLY***

The message is the reply to an earlier request message (MQMT_REQUEST). The message must be sent to the queue indicated by the ReplyToQ field of the request message. Use the Report field of the request to control how to set the MsgId and CorrelId of the reply.